# Identify whether missing value equals to mean within group

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation, missing-data

I have a dataset below:

```
# dt
Year   ST   CC   ID     M    NonMissing  Tot   GRP_Mean
2004   55   35   60    NA             3    4   174.0000
2005   55   35   60   174             3    4   174.0000
2006   55   35   60   174             3    4   174.0000
2007   55   35   60   174             3    4   174.0000
2004   55   35   61    NA             3    4   158.3333
2005   55   35   61   174             3    4   158.3333
2006   55   35   61   127             3    4   158.3333
2007   55   35   61   174             3    4   158.3333
```

I created the mean by groups as below:

```
dt[, GRP_Mean := mean(M, na.rm = T), by = .(ST, CC, ID)]
```

How can I identify whether `M` equals to `GRP_Mean`. For example like this:

```
# dt
Year   ST   CC   ID     M    NonMissing  Tot   GRP_Mean    Equal
2004   55   35   60    NA             3    4   174.0000     TRUE
2005   55   35   60   174             3    4   174.0000     TRUE
2006   55   35   60   174             3    4   174.0000     TRUE
2007   55   35   60   174             3    4   174.0000     TRUE
2004   55   35   61    NA             3    4   158.3333    FALSE
2005   55   35   61   174             3    4   158.3333    FALSE
2006   55   35   61   127             3    4   158.3333    FALSE
2007   55   35   61   174             3    4   158.3333    FALSE
```

`ID == 60` has the same number `174` in column `M` so they have same `GRP_Mean`, give TRUE.

However, `ID == 61` does not have the exact same value under column `M`, give FALSE.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use `%in%` or make a case for `NA` elements with `is.na`

```
library(data.table)  
dt[, Equal := all(GRP_Mean[!is.na(M)] == M[!is.na(M)]), .(ST, CC, ID)]
```

Or it could be

```
dt[, Equal : GRP_Mean == M |is.na(M)]
```

NOTE: The presence of double values could change the `==` to FALSE.  So,  either do a comparison on the `round`ed or integer value (`as.integer(GRP_Mean)[!is.na(M)] == M[!is.na(M)]`  or as @GregorThomas mentioned in the comments, do a difference between the the columns, check if the difference is less than 1e-10 or it is an NA

```
dt[, Equal := abs(GRP_Mean - M) < 1e-10 |!is.na(M)]
```

Comment: Maybe `Equal := abs(GRP_Mean - M) < 1e-10`? `round` seems problematic as it would say 2 is equal to the mean of 1 and 2 due to rounding even.

Comment: The first observation in `ID == 60` gets `FLASE`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @PeterChen i guess you need `any`

Comment: It returns all `TRUE`. I think it needs to add `by`.